# Java beans not able access from jsf file .. JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jstl

I am not able to access class members on appending "." with **carDetails** which is instance of my class as defined in **Faces-config** file as

```
<managed-bean-name>carDetails</managed-bean-name>
<h:outputLabel value="#{carDetails.}"></h:outputLabel>
```

Why carDetails class members like id,name is not visible in jsf file .. but at same time for some other class members are visible..

Comment: Provide your facesconfig and class implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if your getters and setters are defined properly. Sometimes, it helps if you recreate your getter and setters. It's better to use your IDE to generate your getters and setters.